# "to reach his office" vs "will reach his office"

Tags: grammar, present-tense, future-tense, to-infinitive

If I want to use the present or the future in this case, which one is better?

I am talking about instructions that I must tell a person something.

1. Sit on this chair and wait for the manager to reach his office.
2. Sit on this chair and wait for the manager will reach his office.

What is the most best sentence structure?

Comment: First one is right.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is correct.

The second makes no sense in any tense, unless you were saying the second part declaratively, like:

> Sit on this chair and wait, for the manager will reach his office.

But I can't imagine this would be the case here, nor can I think of a scenario where someone would realistically say that.

**Edit:**

As @KateBunting points out, the first (essentially correct) sentence doesn't sound particularly idiomatic, and I can't imagine myself ever saying it to someone.

If the person is being instructed to sit a wait for the manager's attention, some common idiomatic ways of saying this would be:

> Please sit here and wait for the manager.
>
> Take a seat here; the manager [or more commonly perhaps, you'd use the manager's name (or at least title and surname)] won't be long [i.e. let the person know how long they are likely to be waiting].

The second one is very polite and idiomatic and something along those lines would likely be heard in most situations (e.g., attending a job interview or business meeting).

Comment: It's correct, but not very idiomatic. If the chair is in or near the office, "Please sit here and wait for the manager" would be more natural.

Comment: @KateBunting: I think what Chris means is it's "correct" if we understand ***for*** there as introducing a ***reason*** connecting the two clauses: *Sit on this chair and wait, **because** the manager will reach his office* (which might require a rather contrived context, but syntactically it's fine).

Comment: I'm sure at least somebody at some time will have said *Sit there and wait, **for** everything comes to he who waits.* But it's essential to have some kind of punctuation before ***for*** there to reflect the pause which would be ***mandatory*** in speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I was referring to the first sentence, which Chris said was correct.

Comment: @KateBunting: I do agree with you, and though I do try to stick to the literal meaning of the OP, unless the question asks for commentary around meaning, I have added a discussion around this to my answer - thanks!